# bind a click event and pass href attribute to a function

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have the following links (buttons) on a page that I need to instead of it going to the link to call a function instead and pass the url of the respective button clicked via a variable to that function.
There may be more than 3 links (buttons) on the page but they all need to call the same function but pass the respective href valve of the button clicked on.
My assumption is I need to do a bind of some sort but not really sure how to do it in jquery. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Edit: Unfortunately there are no id's for any of the anchors but the only way I can say to target the anchors is the begining of the href attribute which will always start with "/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode="

```
<td width="36%" align="right"> 
<a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=884280"> 
<IMG SRC="/v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/buttons/btn_addtocart_small.gif" ALIGN=absmiddle BORDER=0></A> 
</td>

<td width="36%" align="right"> 
<a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=9857%2D116%2D003"> 
<IMG SRC="/v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/buttons/btn_addtocart_small.gif" ALIGN=absmiddle BORDER=0></A> 
</td> 


<td width="36%" align="right"> 
<a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=70367301P"> 
 <IMG SRC="/v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/buttons/btn_addtocart_small.gif" ALIGN=absmiddle BORDER=0></A> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery pretty easily.

**Let's create a sample function:**

```
function someFunction(href) {
    //do something with url
    alert(href);
}
```

**And then in jQuery, you can easily pass the href attribute to the function:**

To get all elements starting with that prefix, simply use this code.

```
$("a[href^='/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode']").click(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    someFunction(href);
    return false;
});
```

The return false will prevent the link from going to that page.

Comment: If I have other href's on the page wouldn't I need to target like $("a[href^='/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=']").click(function ()
and wouldn't the function need to be function someFunction(href) {
instead of function someFunction(url) {
??????

Comment: And inside the custom function you can name the parameter whatever you like, as long as you use the same name inside your function.

function blah(foo, bar) {
   alert(foo + bar);
}

Comment: Gonna check it an let you know but it looks like it will work, will let you know!!! THX